# Save multiple files from a awk command line

Tags: shell, awk

I would like to filter a file based on the number (1 up to 30) at the first column and save one file for the lines that correspond to the filtering parameters. So, at the end, 30 files should be created. I am trying to do this using a for loop using shell and awk, but it is not working.

```
for (( K=1; K <= 30; K++ )); do awk '{if($1==$K) print $0}' example_file.map > example_file_CHR${K}.map; done
```

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output. We do NOT need a sample input file 30+ lines long and 30 output files for you to demonstrate your problem - 3 instead of 30 should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

what you need is something like this...

```
awk '1<=$1 && $1<=30 {print > "file_"$1}' file
```

no need for a the bash loop.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Actually, I could solve the problem using the follow command line:

for K in {1..30}; do awk -v a=$K '{if($1==a) print $0}' ../plink_gwas_sample_filtered_maf_geno_02_03_17.map > plink_gwas_subfert_CHR${K}.map; done

Comment: yes, there are multiple ways to implement a task which you have to judge performance, maintainability, compliance, simplicity etc.

Comment: Thank you, Karakfa!